# How much of an underground area must be removed and rebuilt to stop mobs from spawning?

Tags: terraria

So im trying to build an underground fortress as my bank world. I've built an area big enough so that if i stand in the middle of the fortress I can only see the outlining walls of what i have built. The problem stems from having enemies that are able to teleport past walls or just go right through them entirely. In hardmode if I go towards the outer walls enemies attack me through the walls and i have to constantly be on my gaurd. I want a place where I dont have to worry about being attacked specially in a bank world where I am organizing and finding stuff or creating stuff.

**How much of an underground area must be removed and rebuilt to stop mobs from spawning?**

Comment: The easiest option would be to not start hardmode in your "bank world", kill the Eye of Cthulhu once, and build a floating fortress instead. Nothing can get to you that way.

Comment: bleh hardmode is the only way to go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just get all the NPC's houses around your bank. Every NPC increases the area that mobs won't spawn. When you have all the NPC's around the bank you won't have any mobs bothering you.

Comment: Unless there's a Blood Moon, Solar Eclipse or invasion in progress... town safety goes poof under those conditions.